# How to store fixed length string in c

Tags: c, arrays, string

I would like to read some fixed length string in a text file and store them in an array. 
The way I read the strings is by fscanf(fp,"%c",&char[]);

However, as the data are seperated by white space, I would like the array index to indicate each string instead of each character.

How would I do that? Should I use `fgets()` with certain length instead of `fgetc()`?
Thanks

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000000  //one row of double = sizeof(Double) *4400
#define keyLength  15


void readKey(char* fileName)
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i, j;
    char  ch;


    if ((fp = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("can not open this file!\n");
    exit(1);
    }

  int row = 0;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
  {
    if (ch == '\n')
    row++;
  }   //Count the line

  rewind(fp); //Going back to the head of the matrix

  int col = 0;
  while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != '\n') //(ch=fgetc(fp))!='\n'&&(ch=fgetc(fp))!='\r'
  {
    if (ch == ' ')
        col++;
  }
  col++; //Count the col

  char** jz = malloc(row * sizeof(char*)); //Allocate spaces
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    jz[i] = malloc(col * keyLength*sizeof(char));

  rewind(fp);

  for (i = 0; i < row; i++) //Read in the data
    for (j = 0; j < col * keyLength; j++) {
      if (!fscanf(fp, "%c", &jz[i][j])) {
        break;
      }
    }

//Print the matrix
  for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < col * keyLength; j++) {
      printf("%c", jz[i][j]);
      if (j + 1 == col) printf("\n");
    }
  fclose(fp);

  printf("%d row, %d  col ",row,col);

}



 int main(void) {

readKey("keys.txt");

}
```

I print the matrix to check if the scanning is successful.
[image]
[image]

Comment: you can try fread. size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream)

Comment: `if (j + 1 == col) printf("\n");` is wong. `j` isn't number of column.

Comment: from the man page for fscanf():   On success, these functions return the number of input  items  success‐
       fully  matched  and  assigned;  this can be fewer than provided for, or
       even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

       The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before  either
       the  first  successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.  EOF is
       also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
       for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set to indicate the
       error.

Comment: in general the posted code logic is quite 'iffy' as it assumes that each line of the input contains the same number of columns.  the posted code assumes that each column is the same width.  The posted code assumes that each line has the same number of columns.   None of these assumptions are backed by the question text.

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1. Multiplying by 1 has no effect. Suggest removing that expression from this line: `jz[i] = malloc(col * keyLength*sizeof(char));` and any other line where this expression is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple example of reading from file with fgets()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 6

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int i = 0;
  FILE *file_ptr;
  char *string=(char*)calloc(LINE_LENGTH,sizeof(char));

  file_ptr = fopen("file.txt", "r");

  while(1)
    {
      if(fgets(string, LINE_LENGTH, file_ptr) == NULL)
         break;
      fgetc(file_ptr);
      printf("\nline[%d] = %s\n", i+1, string);
      i++;
    }

  fclose(file_ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

file.txt

```
12344 45678 99870 33389 11234
```

Answer (score 0):

When `row` and `col` are determined
allocate by following way:

```
char (*jz)[col][keyLength] = malloc(row * col * keyLength);//meant char jz[row][col][keyLength]
```

Read from a file:

```
for(i = 0; i < row; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < col; ++j){
        fscanf(fp, "%s", jz[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Print the matrix:

```
for(i = 0; i < row; ++i){
    for(j = 0; j < col; ++j){
        if(j)
            putchar(' ');
        printf("%s", jz[i][j]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```